# NoClassDefFoundError while packaging module with jar dependencies into archive-jar

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to create a utility jar which I can add to my other projects in the future to save some time while doing many of the same things over and over again.

Here is my project structure:

com.joul 
--src 
----some.package 
------ClassImportingJOML.java 
--module-info.java 
--->`requires org.joml`;

exampleProject 
--lib 
----joul.jar

--src 
----main 
------Main.java 
------->`ClassImportingJOML c = new ClassImportingJOML();`

I stumbled across modules and created my own. I make use of the `org.joml` module and mark it as a dependency in my `module-info.java` file. However, when I package this module into an archive-jar and add it to the module path of another project and run the code; I'm getting the same error: `NoClassDefFoundError` caused by `ClassNotFoundException`.

This only happens when I instantiate a class which imports that module. The exception is thrown in that class and not somewhere else. If anyone has any idea how I can create a jar such that `exampleProject` doesn't have to add org.joml to its dependencies please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Does it help when you try like this when you run it?

`java -jar --add-modules your-module-name your-app.jar`

Comment: Well that doesn't change my NoDef error because the module I'm adding also has a dependency which is where the issue lies